# Create sub-category off General category in Import Wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

[image]

Is there a way to add sub-category to General category in Import Wizard so that my wizards appear in General -> MySubCategory -> My Import Wizard? I am able to add my Wizard by referencing org.eclipse.ui.Basic category for my wizard, but if I define parent for my category:

```xml
<category
        id="my.import.category"
        name="MySubCategory"
        parentCategory="org.eclipse.ui.Basic"/>
  <wizard
        category="my.import.category"
        class="my.MyImportWizard"
        icon="icons/icon.gif"
        id="my.import.wizard"
        name="My Import Wizard">
  </wizard>
```

It does not seem to work. I was under impression that that's what parentCategory element suppose to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add parent category when defining wizard with given category, so here it would be:

```xml
<category
    id="my.import.category"
    name="MySubCategory"
    parentCategory="org.eclipse.ui.Basic"/>
<wizard
    category="org.eclipse.ui.Basic/my.import.category"
    class="my.MyImportWizard"
    icon="icons/icon.gif"
    id="my.import.wizard"
    name="My Import Wizard">
```

Thanks paulweb515, as always.